# How do I overload the I/O operators  C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have created a class that allows the user to input their mailing address, order date, type of cookie ordered and the quantity. There were other errors, but I stayed late and with the assistance of my prof, I have fixed them. Now all that is left is that I need to be able to change code to overload the I/O stream operators so that the objects may be used in standard input and output statements.

I'm not sure what all part of the code everyone will need to see, but I'm going to post the parts I believe are needed for what I'm trying to do.

I need to have it where in the output(), I have `cout << order << endl;` I will look over the net and will hopefully have it ready by tonight. Thanks for everyone's input.

**Was instructed to take down my code due to other students from class copying my code pieces to do their work (knew it was possible but didn't think about it)**

However, my code is complete.

Comment: I hint - whenever I see phrases like "I'm under a tight time restriction", I take my time answering. My time is at least as valuable as yours.

Comment: You're more likely to get answers if you accept the most helpful answer to your questions by using the check mark.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth - I'm not saying anyone's time is more inmportant than anyone elses. I have completed much of the code and just need assistance completing it out. Just as with all forums from all places on the net, no help is just wasting time you just stated was "My time is at least as valuable as yours" which you wasted your "valuable" time to type that just as I'm wasting my time to type this. It's all null to productivity. Thanks for at least reading it over.

Comment: I greatly appreciate everyone else's input and will be looking into everything and will hopefully finish this out. This and 2 other proj in Java due Sat.

Comment: The program/post has been greatly edited. Re-read over it if still interested. All that is left is the overlaoding to change order.output() to cout << order << endl; and so forth.

Comment: You're trying to do way too much within the >> operator. That operator should exclusively be used to extract data from the input stream and store it in the current object.  Writing to the output stream should be done outside the >> operator.  Take a look at http://functionx.com/cpp/Lesson25.htm - they've got some examples of how to do what you should be doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement two functions: 
`basic_ostream & operator<< (basic_ostream& ostr, const CookieOrder& co)`
`basic_istream & operator>> (basic_istream& istr, CookieOrder& co)`

the `operator<<=` function will be called when you use `cout << order << endl;` and the `operator>>` function will be called when you use the `>>` (stream extraction) operator. Be very careful how you implement the stream extraction operator.

You may want to declare either of these as  `friend` to the `CookieOrder`, as that will allow the function to access the private parts of the class as if the function is a member of the class.

---

edit to respond to changes in the question

delcare your class as before:

> class CookieOrder {
>     public:
>       // public methods as before
>     private:
>       // private parts as before
>   };
>   `basic_ostream` & operator<< (basic_ostream& ostr, const CookieOrder& co);
>   `basic_istream` & operator>> (basic_istream& istr, CookieOrder& co);

Implement the two functions using only the public interface of the CookieOrder class.

For example:

> `basic_ostream` & operator<< (basic_ostream& ostr, const CookieOrder& co)
>   {
>      ostr << co.get_customerName() << endl;
>      /* the rest of the output */
>   }

These functions **are not** members of the CookieOrder class, they are normal functions with no special access to the CookieOrder class or instanaces of the class.

Comment: How would I do it for the input part. b/c it I dont want to set the cookie type or quantity until the program runs the methods to check for valid input from the user.

Comment: Thank you very very much. You greatly helped me in solving the issue. I was able to figure it out and now have everything working. 

THANKS! Happy Holidays!

Comment: `basic_[io]stream` classes are templates, you either need to specify template parameters for them, make the operator overloads into function templates (and specify template parameters for `basic_[io]stream`), or use `[io]stream` (take off the `basic_`) which are the common `<char>` instantiations.

Answer (score 1):

As far as comparison is concerned, you'd be better off comparing all upper or all lower (rather than each word's first letter upper), it's simpler to set things that way.

Moreover you should get into the habit of putting braces around code

Why do you have a magic number of 6 in your loop?  Especially when you only have five (5) elements.

Perhaps the loop should be

...

```
int loop_size = sizeof(flavors)/sizeof(flavors[0]);

for (int i = 0; i < loop_size; ++i)

{

   if (flavors[i] == cookieOrdered)
   {
       valid_option = true;
       break;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hint: lookup Case insensitive string comparison in C++